# insert command denied in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table from which, when I select data with username and password, it works but when I insert some data in that table with same username and password it shows me the error

```
INSERT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
```

I searched using Google and someone else had the same problem with db size.  I checked my db and when I go directly to phpmyadmin to insert data into the table, it works, but when I call a query to the table from a PHP script, it gives me the error.

Comment: It might be a privilege problem.

Comment: check for the permission of the mysql account grant all privilages

Comment: Show us your PHP code. It most probably is a privilege problem. The script needs to login to MySQL as a user that has privilege to INSERT INTO the table (or into all the database).

Comment: i have checked all privileges checkbox but still problem

Comment: It could be a problem of allocated space for DBs. Check your hosting plan and ask for checking the allocated space for the database.

Comment: maybe wrong database is selected.

Comment: I had the same error; I specified a wrong database name in my insert script: `INSERT INTO db1.tablename`, where `username@localhost` only has permission to insert into database `db2`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a permissions problem. Log into a MySQL prompt with the user the app is running as, and enter this query:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

This will show you the privileges ([grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) in MySQL-speak) that the current user has. My guess is that you won't see INSERT privileges for the given table. You will need the root user to grant you permission by running this query:

```
GRANT INSERT ON 'db'.'tablename' TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

Comment: i run the query in my phpmyadmin and it gives me the error. `#1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'uname'@'localhost' for table 'tablename'
`

Comment: Ok, you don't have permission to view your permissions. You'll either have to log in as root to check, or contact whoever manages your hosting and ask.

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem after moving my site from one hosting account to another. The problem was caused by a SQL query (`INSERT`) that referenced the old database. replacing the old db with the new db name (or just removing the db name altogether) solved the problem. But this mistake stumped the support people at my hosting company.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO old_db_name.table_name ( ) VALUES ();
```

Changed to:

```
INSERT INTO new_db_name.table_name ( ) VALUES ( );
```

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: You won't believe it so easy to mess this up especially if your hosting company insist prefixing table!

Comment: At first I thought why this answer has more upvotes than the accepted one. Now that I've fixed my wrong database name issue, I understand the reason for this :D

Answer (score 11):

Check your SQL code.

And just delete dbName if you have.

Example:

```
insert into `dbName`.`tableName` ( columns ) values ( values );
```

Change to:

```
insert into `tableName` ( columns ) values ( values );
```

Comment: If the user has the privilege to write to that table anyway, why is explicitly providing the path to it (by including the database name) breaking it? Please could you maybe provide some documentation reference about this? Thanks

Comment: Beyond all reason this worked.  The db name should have no impact and when I compare it to another stored proc that works and does have the name...baffling, but it did work.  The host I use does not allow much in control of permissions so trying to investigate is difficult.

Answer (score 4):

This also happened to me and the problem is that when you call the command `INSERT` in your php file you must have specified another database.

In short, find where your INSERT command is and check the part `your_database_name` below

```
"INSERT INTO \`your_database_name\`.\`your_table_name\`
```

That might solve your problem. Of course, if all privileges are granted for you.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.

Our hosted mysql provider removed the insert permission when the max db volume was reached.

Using the

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

command (mentioned in answer above) in mysql helped me figure this out.

We used JAWS DB MYSQL, but other hosted mysql providers may use the same method.

Comment: It was the same problem for me. My website went down, giving only a database error note on screen (for frontend and backend) saying "INSERT command denied to user"... The problem turned out to be one table of a "comments" plugin where data of people posting comments were stored, and this had become junked up over time by bots with about 1 GB of stuff. Emptying (SQL: truncate) the table helped. After about 15 minutes, the website was then available again (however not immediately after emptying the table.

Answer (score 2):

In your query you might be using table name with database name "INSERT INTO DB_NAME.table_name ..." where you database user do not have insert permissions for DB_NAME. So this error is coming because query is pointing to the table of another database.

You need to remove the database name or use correct database name either.

Comment: This was my mistake - development code referenced the development database - when should have been referencing the production database

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have an open connection to the database.

If you have separate functions  for database connection and for insert values check the database connection is open or not.