# Error 1142: SELECT and LOCK TABLE commands denied

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1142

I reinstalled the server running MySQL. I had created a backup of the database by using MySQL Workbench. Now I'm trying to import the dump in to the database trough the same program but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 656: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user 'root'@'MIKKOS' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'
```

I tought that root had full privileges. I ran the following but the same error appears with the previous query after executing this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

It also appears when running locally (root@localhost).

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Check which databases MySQL Workbench included in the dumpfile. I believe it defaults to dumping everything, including DBs like `user` and `performance_schema`. Those are the problem, your grant tables are probably fine.

Remove the unneeded databases, especially `performance_schema` and MySQL will likely import the dumpfile without errors.

Answer (score -1):

You need to repair internal table structure after reinstallation a newer MySQL server. To do so try:

```
REPAIR TABLE `events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name`;
```

It would be better to drop database and restore it from full mysql database dump if you have one.

Comment: I tried to repair the table as you advised. `Error Code: 1142. SELECT,INSERT command denied to user 'root'@'MIKKOS' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'`

Comment: [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698981/insert-command-denied-in-mysql)

Comment: This is what it outputs (2 rows): `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'XXX' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, TRIGGER ON `%`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`
I can see those two privileges there.

Comment: First of all clear privelege mess - it will help. To do so inspect MySQL system database called mysql: `USE mysql; SHOW TABLES; SELECT * FROM user;` etc. You can directly remove unneeded rows. And do not forget to check per column priveleges.