# Importing sql file in workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql file called backup.sql, I'm trying to import this file using workbench, but at some point, I get this error:

Error:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1758: SELECT, LOCK TABLES command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

I tried the following sql statement, but nothing changed.

```
GRANT SELECT,LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Try searching for MYSQL ERROR 1142... there are several Q&A you should check, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423686/error-1142-select-and-lock-table-commands-denied

Comment: I'm confused! root user should have all the privileges, why is this happening? I tried to search for this error but I couldn't make it work.