# access denied for specific user(root user)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

it's not a duplicate so, please.

I'm getting the following error while inserting data into table.

```
INSERT command denied to user 'next'@'localhost' for table 'synonyms_facility'
```

while my `query` looks like something this:

```
INSERT INTO job_requests(...) VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `start_date` = '10/26/2015', `end_date` = '01/22/2016', `rate` = '$89.00';
```

I don't have this `table(synonyms_facility)` in `database`.

`next` is user that I use to login to `PHP My Admin(cPanel as well)`.

can someone points me to right direction?

Thanks in advance.

PS: while executing above query in client, it gives error something like this:

```
#1142 - INSERT command denied to user 'next'@'localhost' for table 'synonyms_facility'
```

**Edit**

Did try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699061/2558525) suggested by Mike.

that gave me this result on executing `SHOW GRANTS;`

> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'next'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `next\_hc`.* TO 'next'@'localhost'

tried this query

```
GRANT INSERT ON 'db'.'tablename' TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

(with changed wildcards)

it gave me another error:

```
 #1045 - Access denied for user 'next'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert command denied in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698981/insert-command-denied-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you log it to MySQL at all? E.g either from SSH via command line client, or from a stand-alone php script bypassing phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Mike: I've tried that solution, here is outcome `#1044 - Access denied for user 'next'@'localhost' to database 'next_hc'`

Comment: yes, I can login using `Putty` @SashaPachev

Comment: @Mubin So why don't you grant permissions for user `'next'@'localhost'` to `'next_hc'` and `'synonyms_facility'`?

Comment: `SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='synonyms_facility'` - what does it give you?

Comment: This is a common symptom of the database not selected, or database not existing??

Comment: @SashaPachev: by executing your query, get this. `Empty set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: @Tristan: I tried to connect it using `PHP` and `mysqli_object` indicates me no error.

Comment: @Tristan: `mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => 5.5.42 [client_version] => 50542 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.46-cll [server_version] => 50546 [stat] => Uptime: 835337 Threads: 2 Questions: 580784 Slow queries: 6 Opens: 510 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 245 Queries per second avg: 0.695 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 103037 [warning_count] => 0 `

Comment: @Mubin Did you execute those grant commands as the mysql root user?

Comment: I don;t have root user access.

Comment: also, it should insert things if I use custom created user from `cPanel`

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS` query give you?

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'next'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON next\_hc.* TO 'next'@'localhost'

-----as updated in question

Comment: The only way to be able to execute that query is by granting that user permission to do it. I haven't used cPanel in years, but there might be something in there that would allow you to grant permission for that user to access that database. This is something that *requires* root access to do, however cPanel might have some sort of wrapper that executes as root to grant permissions to tables you have created.

Comment: created a database, then created a new user, grant all privileges to that user on that database, but still same.

Comment: If you granted the permissions for that user, it should work. If not, contact your host and tell them that the cPanel grant doohickey for granting permissions to databases is not working. Maybe the cPanel user doesn't have GRANT permissions.

Comment: got it, thanks sir @Mike, really appreciate your advice. not working though, but going to write to Admin

Answer (score -1):

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you tried to log out with the door button below the "phpMyAdmin" logo.